# Using Capacitor Plugins as Script Include (not with bundle/module loader)

Tags: javascript, capacitor

The Capacitor JS documentation handily documents how the core can be included without using a bundle/module loader [on this page](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/web#using-capacitor-as-a-script-include), but what is fails to do is then provide an example of how to then implement a plugin.

For example, here's how the Capacitor docs show how to use the Camera plugin:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';

const { Camera } = Plugins;

const photo = await Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  allowEditing: true,
  saveToGallery: true
});
```

If I'm using the `<script src="capacitor.js"></script>` version of including capacitor, what's the non-module version of the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Capacitor.Plugins.Camera.getPhoto({
  quality: 100,
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  allowEditing: true,
  saveToGallery: true
})
```

Comment: Thank you. Just needed that simple answer and suddenly all of the plugins are available to me.

Comment: Ok, maybe I spoke too soon. If I do something like ````console.log(Capacitor.Plugins.Device.getInfo());```` it's empty. Does the ```await``` command come into play here somewhere?

Comment: Capacitor plugins return promises, you can use await or the .then

Comment: found this answer extremly useful. But I am now left with the question how to use non core plugins without a build system. E.g.: If I installed an external plugin with `npm install @capacitor-community/date-picker`: How can I add the plugin without a bundle/module loader?

Comment: All plugins get included into Capacitor.Plugins object. For 3rd party plugins probably won't work on web, but on iOS and Android it will work because the plugin's javascript is generated by Capacitor, not shipped by the plugin.

Comment: In Capacitor v3, this no longer works since plugins are not included in capacitor.js but are separate. Any thoughts on using plugins with a script include in version 3?